# Ultrabook or Thin Laptop with great battery life for Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, battery, ultrabook

Any recommendations on a great ultrabook or thin-enough laptop with great battery life for running Ubuntu?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic. See the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Flagged for closing.

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for the reminder. BTW this was not a frivolous question. I'm an experienced Ubuntu user who was just interested in great battery performance. But I'll find a different place to ask around.

Answer (score 2):

Dell has [XPS 13](http://www.dell.com/us/soho/p/xps-13-linux/pd) super expensive ultrabook preloaded with Ubuntu. But technically you can buy any ultrabook or zenbook, and blow windows away and install Ubuntu in it. Few models I would suggest to look at are, [Samsung Series 9](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/series-9-notebooks), [Zenbook](http://zenbook.asus.com/zenbook/), [Vizio ultrabook](http://www.vizio.com/thin-light/overview), [hp envy spectre](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/envy14-spectre/index.html#.UUi1BTfk9I0). I think in the end it really depends on your budget.

I personally would buy an ultrabook which has Windows 7 with it (not Windows 8) and dual boot it with Ubuntu.

Comment: [Thinkpad X1 Carbon](https://dague.net/2014/01/11/thinkpad-x1-carbon-awesome-linux-laptop/) is a good candidate.